# Create a "Feeling Luky" widget Magento 2

Tags: magento2, widgets

I need to create a "feeling lucky" widget that have 2 fields:

price range & color (both drop down lists), when user chooses his preferred price and color, I need to show 3-4 random products that match his selection.

I am lost on where to start on this, as this is my first Magento 2 widget.

I have tried to watch a few tutorials but nothing answered my questions.

Could anybody help me with main steps to do it or even recommend a good course.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it sounds like you're going to need to create a module! I recommend understanding how Magento works before diving into customizations.

My personal favorite place to start with Magento is Alan Storm's Magento 2 series. https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_mvvm_mvc/

This is where a lot of the members of the Magento community get started.

I like coolryan's blog as well.  He explains a lot of the major features of Magento in a simplified way: http://www.coolryan.com/magento-2/